# onChange event handler with select element that can show hidden element

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This is my code below what I'm trying to do is only if I select "NO" the table row should be shown. I tried this `onchange` event and DOM so I can get hidden table should shown, but I don't know why it's not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>


function showstuff(){
   document.getElementById(show).style.display="block";
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form>
Choose which browser you prefer:
<select id="browsers" onchange="showstuff(show)">
<option value="Maybe">May Be</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="NO">No</option>
</select>
</form>

<table>
       <tr id="show" style="display: none">
<td>Write why no?</td>
<td><input type="text" name="whyno"></td>
</tr>


</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, DOM element IDs are strings, so you have to delimit them with single or double quotes, i.e. `'show'`, and if you want to pass a certain value to a function, you must define the argument name, i.e. `function showstuff(argument)`, and then use the argument in the rest of your function.

*Edit*: I modified your function to take **three** arguments: the element you want to show, the option that must be checked, and a reference to the element that was changed. For example, `showstuff('show', 'NO', this)` will show the element with `id="show"` only if the option `'NO'` is selected.

Change your function to this:

```
function showstuff(element, option, t){
   if(t.options[t.selectedIndex].value==option){
      document.getElementById(element).style.display="block";
   }else{
      document.getElementById(element).style.display="none";
   }
}
```

And HTML to this:

```
<select id="browsers" onchange="showstuff('show', 'NO', this);">
```

[jsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/jcoc611/vPu6e/)

Comment: Yeah, It's working, but what I want is element should be shown only If I select "No"

Comment: I changed a bit the code to hide the field once you select something different again, and added a live example in jsFiddle. It should work for you now.